# Changing behavior help

Tags: behavior, biting

Our new three month old kitten has decided we are okay and loves us. Head bunting, snuggling, purring and napping on us every day. However with me (mommy) she loves to nuzzle my neck and face, lick my hair and then bites me on the chin or neck when I get home and at bedtime. I put her down, out of the room, or give her a little spank and a firm "NO", but she keeps coming back to the same thing.

I think she loves me and just gets excited, but it hurts. How can I change this behavior? She loves to sleep on the pillow next to me or accross my neck or snuggled under my arm. But the biting part has to stop. Please help